# How to install package from github

Tags: github, installation, package

I would like to use psd-tools package from github. 
Given I am not a programer, I found the installation process difficult to follow.
Can someone advice in simple terms how to install and use the psd-tool package.
Apparently, this is all done via the terminal in OSX.

If I understand correctly the package requires python, pip, pillow and packbits to run correctly.

Python is pre installed in OSX. Pip and packbits need to be installed. This where I start to get lost with the installation procedure.

Once the psd-tools package is installed, I am not sure how to call the package to test a psd file.

[github psd-tools package](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools)

Answer (score 0):

- [Download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psd-tools#downloads) Python package for working with Adobe Photoshop PSD files

**Installation**

```
pip install psd-tools
```

Pillow should be installed if you want work with PSD image and layer data: export images to PNG, process them. PIL library should also work.

```
pip install Pillow
```

**Note**

In order to extract images from 32bit PSD files PIL/Pillow must be built with LITTLECMS or LITTLECMS2 support.
psd-tools also has a rudimentary support for Pymaging. Pymaging installation instructions are available in pymaging docs. If you want to use Pymaging instead of Pillow you'll also need packbits library:

```
pip install packbits
```

Usage of PSD-Tools and How to use it Read this.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: I downloaded installed the python 3.4 .2.

Comment: I downloaded installed the python 3.4 .2. I later become aware that python 2.7 was already installed. Version 2.7 is in /usr/bin/python2.7 and version 3.4 is in usr/local/bin/python3.4. The next step is installing pip. To install pip I have to locate Scripts directory in the Python installation on my system and change the PATH variable to point to this directory. I cd to the python directory in either version and I am unable to list the contents of the directory to check if the Scripts exists. [link]http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html